# XSLT: Apply template to Nodes that don't contain a specific subnode

Tags: xml, xslt, docbook

I'm using docbook and am using a template which inserts zero-width characters into my table entries.  Which is good, but I need to have the template **NOT** applied if the table entry includes a `<para>` element.  So, is there a way I can apply the template to all `<entry>` that do not contain a `<para>`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:d="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">
<xsl:import href="urn:docbkx:stylesheet"/>

...

<xsl:template match="text()[parent::d:entry]">
    <xsl:call-template name="intersperse-with-zero-spaces">
        <xsl:with-param name="str" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<xsl:template match="d:entry[not(d:para)]">` matches any `entry` elements not having any `para` children. `<xsl:template match="d:entry[not(descendant::d:para)]">` matches any `entry` elements not having any `para` descendants.

Or for your posted template you could use `<xsl:template match="text()[parent::d:entry[not(d:para)]]">`.

Comment: This is right. But last sugestion with foward and backward axis... Why don't `d:entry[not(d:para)]/text()`, instead?

Comment: Alejandro, you are right, using `d:entry[not(d:para)]/text()` is more straight-forward than `text()[parent::d:entry[not(d:para)]]` and I would probably write it that way when I start out on my own. But I started out with the `text()[parent::d:entry]` in the original post and adapted that, that's why I ended up the other way round. Ace, if you are still reading, consider to use `match="d:entry[not(d:para)]/text()"` instead of `match="text()[parent::d:entry[not(d:para)]]"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:template match="text()[parent::d:entry[not(.//d:para)]]">
    <xsl:call-template name="intersperse-with-zero-spaces">
        <xsl:with-param name="str" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```